# How can I avoid running into transaction log space issus in DB2 when refreshing MQTs?

Tags: database, db2

I have a MQT which refreshes a 120 million row table. How can I avoid running into transaction log space issus in DB2 when refreshing MQTs? What are the different techniques available in Db2?

Comment: This really belongs on dba.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would build the table as `NOT LOGGED INITIALLY`. This will allow you to perform anything against the table and it will not log it until you issue a `COMMIT` statement. Then before you `REFRESH` the table again, make sure you ALTER the table to put it back into a `NOT LOGGED INITIALLY` state.

See [information center for `CREATE TABLE` statement](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v10r5/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0000927.html) and look at the `NOT LOGGED INITIALLY` clause.

Comment: NOT LOGGED INITIALLY is not helpful as the APP USER ID in our project doesnt have privileges to perform any ALTER TABLE statements

Comment: You could have a script with the appropriate authorities do the ALTER and the REFRESH.